# VBA Macro based on a specified column named "Carrier" creates or split the column values into a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA Macro, I am trying to create a macro that split data based on a specific column and creates a new workbook for each column values.

Below is my code which gives a lot of errors I am confused to deal with it... the below code is too lengthy is there any way possible to short main is the proper output

```
Sub ExportData()

'Declare variables
Dim ArrayItem As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ArrayOfUniqueValues As Variant
Dim SavePath As String
Dim ColumnHeadingInt As Long
Dim ColumnHeadingStr As String
Dim rng As Range

'Set the worksheet to
Set ws = Sheets("POL")

'Set the save path for the files created
SavePath = "C:\Folder"

'Set variables for the column we want to separate data based on
ColumnHeadingInt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL").Match(Range("Carrier").Value, Range("POL[#Headers]"), 0)
ColumnHeadingStr = "POL[[#All],[" & Range("Carrier").Value & "]]"

'Turn off screen updating to save runtime
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create a temporary list of unique values from the column we want to
'separate our data based on
Range(ColumnHeadingStr & "").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=Range("UniqueValues"), Unique:=True

'Sort our temporary list of unique values
ws.Range("UniqueValues").EntireColumn.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("UniqueValues").Offset(1, 0), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

'Add unique field values into an array
'ArrayOfUniqueValues = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("IV2:IV" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ArrayOfUniqueValues = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("UniqueValues").EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))

'Delete the temporary values
ws.Range("UniqueValues").EntireColumn.Clear

'Loop through our array of unique field values, copy paste into new workbooks and save
For ArrayItem = 1 To UBound(ArrayOfUniqueValues)
    ws.ListObjects("POL").Range.AutoFilter Field:=ColumnHeadingInt, Criteria1:=ArrayOfUniqueValues(ArrayItem)
    ws.Range("POL[#All]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SavePath & ArrayOfUniqueValues(ArrayItem) & Format(Now(), " YYYY-MM-DD ") & ".xlsx", 51
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    ws.ListObjects("POL").Range.AutoFilter Field:=ColumnHeadingInt
Next ArrayItem

ws.AutoFilterMode = False
MsgBox "Finished exporting!"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

[image: OutPut borders got added to all the emplty cells also]

Border got added to all the empty cells also
I coded like this

```
'Autofit
                
                Sheets("POL").UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
                 
                
                'Sorting the range to compact the data.
                With .Parent.Sort
                    .SortFields.Clear
                    .SortFields.Add Key:=RngRange02.Columns(DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn), _
                                    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                    Order:=xlAscending, _
                                    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    .SetRange RngRange02
                    .Header = xlYes
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                    .Apply
                End With
                
                'Apply Border
                
                With Sheets("POL").UsedRange.Borders
                  .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                   .Weight = xlThin
                   .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                 End With
```

I have added 3 more set that changes the sheetname and autofits the column in all excel sheet. All it is working but the problem is with the border which is applying to the empty cells also

Comment: Which error do you get and in which line? Please [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: First I got an error on line "SavePath = "C:\Folder"  then I checked the path and did changes "SavePath = "C:\Folder" like this then now I am getting an error on line "ColumnHeadingInt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL").Match(Range("Carrier").Value, Range("POL[#Headers]"), 0)"  stating object not found error code I saw was 91 ... Since I am new to VBA Macro it is getting more comicated for me so sought it out.

Comment: Your SavePath is missing and end backslash. It won't solve your problem, but it should give you another one if you don't correct it.

Comment: I recommend not to use `.Activate` and to `ActiveWorkbook` where ever possible. Also for **every** of your range objects should be specified in which workbook and worksheet they are eg `ws.Range` or `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range`. If you just write `Range` Excel cannot reliably tell which workbook and worksheet you mean this range to be in, so be as specific as possible and this will prevent a lot of trouble already. Give it a try and update your code in the question if you still get errors.

Comment: Worksheets("POL").Match does not exist. Use Excel.Worksheetfunction.Match and fill it accordingly.

Comment: Some1 please answer

Comment: Did you try the suggestions from the comments? If yes please update the code in your question. Note that we can assist you to fix your issues but the one who needs to do it is actually you. We showed up 3 issues that need to be fixed.

Comment: everything thing tried nothing worked

Comment: Some 1 please help

Comment: Be patient Jay. I've already wrote down some code that might help you. Still not ready though. And i've also other things to do that actually pay my bills. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub ExportAndSave()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngSourceData As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim RngRange01 As Range
    Dim RngRange02 As Range
    Dim StrCarrierColumnHeader As String
    Dim StrSavePath As String
    Dim StrMultipleFileMessage As String
    Dim DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn As Double
    Dim DblCounter01 As Double
    Dim DblCounter02 As Double
    Dim WkbSource As Workbook
    Dim WkbTarget As Workbook
    
    'Turning off screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Setting variables.
    Set WkbSource = ActiveWorkbook
    Set RngSourceData = WkbSource.Sheets("POL").Range("I1:J6")
    StrCarrierColumnHeader = "Carrier"
    StrSavePath = "C:\Folder\"
    
    'Setting DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn to determine what column within RngSourceData _
    contains the StrCarrierColumnHeader. If no such column is found, the subroutine is terminated.
    On Error Resume Next
    DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(StrCarrierColumnHeader, RngSourceData.Rows(1), 0)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "The range " & RngSourceData.Rows(1).Address(False, False) & " contains no column headed " & StrCarrierColumnHeader & ". The subroutine is terminated", vbCritical, "Error"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Setting RngRange01 to cover the data in the carrier column.
    Set RngRange01 = RngSourceData.Columns(DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn).Resize(RngSourceData.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0)
    
    'Covering each cell in RngRange01.
    DblCounter01 = 0
    For Each RngTarget In RngRange01.Cells
        
        'Checking if the code had already met the carrier of RngTarget.
        If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RngSourceData.Parent.Range(RngRange01.Cells(1, 1), RngTarget), RngTarget.Value) = 1 Then
            
            'Cheking if any file dedicated to the given carrier already exists for today.
            If Dir(StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & Format(Now(), " YYYY-MM-DD ") & ".xlsx") = "" Then
                'If no such file exists, it is created and saved.
                Set WkbTarget = Workbooks.Add
                WkbTarget.SaveAs StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & Format(Now(), " YYYY-MM-DD ") & ".xlsx"
            Else
                'Is it does exist, the name is "shifted".
                DblCounter02 = 2
                Do Until Dir(StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & Format(Now(), " YYYY-MM-DD ") & "(" & DblCounter02 & ")" & ".xlsx") = ""
                    DblCounter02 = DblCounter02 + 1
                Loop
                'Carrier and relative file are copied in StrMultipleFileMessage.
                StrMultipleFileMessage = StrMultipleFileMessage & vbCrLf & RngTarget.Value & " in " & RngTarget.Value & Format(Now(), " YYYY-MM-DD ") & "(" & DblCounter02 & ")" & ".xlsx"
                Set WkbTarget = Workbooks.Add
                WkbTarget.SaveAs StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & Format(Now(), " YYYY-MM-DD ") & "(" & DblCounter02 & ")" & ".xlsx"
            End If
            
            'Setting RngRange02 to target the range in the new file where RngSourceData will be copied.
            Set RngRange02 = WkbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(RngSourceData.Rows.Count, RngSourceData.Columns.Count)
            
            With RngRange02
                
                'Copying values.
                RngSourceData.Copy RngRange02
                
                'Filtering the range to clear the list of unwanted data.
                .AutoFilter Field:=DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn, Criteria1:="<>" & RngTarget.Value
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).ClearFormats
                
                'Removing the filter.
                .AutoFilter
                
                'Sorting the range to compact the data.
                With .Parent.Sort
                    .SortFields.Clear
                    .SortFields.Add Key:=RngRange02.Columns(DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn), _
                                    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                    Order:=xlAscending, _
                                    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    .SetRange RngRange02
                    .Header = xlYes
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                    .Apply
                End With
                
            End With
            
            'Saving and closing WkbTarget.
            WkbTarget.Close savechanges:=True
            
        End If
        
        'Setting DblCounter01.
        DblCounter01 = DblCounter01 + 1
    Next
    
    'Enabling screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'Reporting if any carrier had its data reported in a "twin" file.
    If StrMultipleFileMessage <> "" Then
        StrMultipleFileMessage = "The following carriers had already one or more dedicated files at the given path. Their data were saved accordingly to this list:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & StrMultipleFileMessage
        MsgBox StrMultipleFileMessage, , "Multiple dedicated files"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

You will probably have to edit the setting of some variables (RngSourceData for sure i'd say).

Comment: Hi, @Evil Blue Monkey appreciate your efforts. However, the output is not in the order I have pasted all the output in the above question with screenshots. Firstly, for a few carries, it creates a temp file in the folder as highlighted above and the output inside the created excel sheet is not the same as what it is in the original sheet. Like in the original sheet the top row and last column are highlighted the split data should be exactly same as what it is in the original sheet. please help

Comment: Ok, the format problem can be solved. In my code i just copied the values, not the formats. Reguarding the temp files: i think it's due to their name. They have points. I'll check if it's possible to make them as xlsx files even if they have points in their name.

Comment: `WkbTarget.SaveAs StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & Format(Now(), " YYYY-MM-DD ") & "(" & DblCounter02 & ")", 51` is missing the file extension. Just change to `… & "(" & DblCounter02 & ").xlsx", 51`

Comment: Yep, yep. Already done it, thank you. ;) I thought that since 51 was specified, there would have been no need. And i didn't expect any points in the name. I've just put the ".xlsx" and removed the 51 since clearly there is no need for it. Anyway, Jay Sameer: try it now. Any other request?

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Evil Blue Monkey and @Peh it works.... much appreciated. thanks a lot...

Comment: Hi @EvilBlueMonkey the macro is not adding the border in the extracted file I have given a condition after "With condition set"   'Apply Border
                
                With Sheets("POL").UsedRange.Borders
                  .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                   .Weight = xlThin
                   .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                 End With
but this is applying to all employ rows also

Comment: Please see my edits above in the question section... @EvilBlueMonkey

Comment: You are applying it to the UsedRange. Try to better define your range. Maybe `With Sheets("POL").Range(Sheets("POL").Range("A1"), Sheets("POL").Cells(Sheets("POL").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row, Sheets("POL").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column)).Borders`.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Hi it's not working... actually the main POL sheet has border so when a new file is created that border goes off cant we do something for that when it creates new file the data border should be as it is

Comment: This is getting too much out of topic and i am not sure what's your problem now. The code i wrote should copy formats too. You should open another question with the code you are using and explain your problem better.

Comment: Ok @EvilBlueMonkey I will open another question... anyways thanks for the guidance this module is working great